# AtlasMap cannot connect element to the selected mapping

Tags: atlasmap

I am trying to concatenate multiple source fields into one target field. Some elements are not a problem to combine with, others cannot be combined as you can see in the picture. I would like to concatenate the name and value from the source structure to the value of the target structure, but it is not possible.

[an indication of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xjup.png)

NewGetterRequest.xsd - source structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:om="http://ordermanagement/Types"
    xmlns:tns="http://ordermanagement/Messages" xmlns:rfs="/rfs/v1/T1675667583418Converted/JsonSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ordermanagement/Messages">

    <complexType name="GetterRequest">
        <annotation>
            <documentation>Component Execute request</documentation>
        </annotation>
        <sequence>
            <element ref="tns:triggerComponentExecute" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="getterRequest" type="tns:GetterRequest" />

    <complexType name="UdfType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="evaluationPriority" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
            <element name="type" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
            <element name="flavor" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
            <element name="name" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
            <element name="value" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
            <element name="originalValue" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="UdfListType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="udf" type="tns:UdfType" minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="UdfList" type="tns:UdfListType" />

    <complexType name="OrderLineType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="orderLineNumber" type="string" />
            <element name="productID" type="string" />
            <element name="productVersion" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
            <element name="action" type="string" />
            <element name="actionMode" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
            <element name="quantity" type="long" />
            <element name="uom" type="string" />
            <element name="subscriberID" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
            <element name="linkID" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
            <element name="inventoryID" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
            <element name="eol" type="boolean" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="OrchIdentType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="orderID" type="string" minOccurs="1" />
            <element name="orderRef" type="string" minOccurs="1" />
            <element name="planID" type="string" minOccurs="1" />
            <element name="planItemID" type="string" minOccurs="1" />
            <element name="processComponentID" type="string" minOccurs="1" />
            <element name="processComponentName" type="string" minOccurs="1" />
            <element name="processComponentVersion" type="string"
                minOccurs="0" />
            <element name="originator" type="string" minOccurs="1" />
            <element name="priority" type="integer" minOccurs="1" />
            <element name="subscriptionId" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
            <element name="userName" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="orchIdentifiers" type="tns:OrchIdentType" />

    <complexType name="PlanItemType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="description" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
            <element name="processComponentType" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
            <element name="processComponentRecordType" type="string"
                minOccurs="0" />
            <element name="orderLine" type="tns:OrderLineType" minOccurs="1"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <element name="action" type="string" />
            <element name="actionMode" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
            <element name="udf" type="tns:UdfType" minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <element name="parentID" type="string" minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <element name="childID" type="string" minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <element name="siblingID" type="string" minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <element name="dependentID" type="string" minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="planItem" type="tns:PlanItemType" />

    <complexType name="ExecuteRequest">
        <annotation>
            <documentation>Orchestrator request message data</documentation>
        </annotation>
        <sequence>
            <element ref="tns:orchIdentifiers" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            <element name="planItem" type="tns:PlanItemType" />
            <element name="sla" minOccurs="0">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="typicalDuration" type="long" />
                        <element name="maximumDuration" type="long" />
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="waitAtMilestoneID" type="string" minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <element name="notifyAtMilestoneID" type="string" minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="executeRequest" type="tns:ExecuteRequest" />

    <complexType name="TriggerComponentExecute">
        <annotation>
            <documentation>Component Execute request</documentation>
        </annotation>
        <sequence>
            <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="tns:executeRequest" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="triggerComponentExecute" type="tns:TriggerComponentExecute" />
</schema>
```

RFS_API.xsd - target structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="/rfs/v1/T1675667583418Converted/JsonSchema" xmlns:tns="/rfs/v1/T1675667583418Converted/JsonSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Rfs_characteristics" type="tns:Rfs_characteristics"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Rfs_characteristics">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Rfs_characteristics" type="tns:Characteristic"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Rfs_status" type="tns:Rfs_status"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="Rfs_status">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="Characteristic_name1" type="tns:Characteristic_name1"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="Characteristic_name1">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="Rfs_action" type="tns:Rfs_action"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="Rfs_action">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="Characteristic_value" type="tns:Characteristic_value"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="Characteristic_value">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="Characteristic" type="tns:Characteristic"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Characteristic">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Rfs_id" type="tns:Rfs_id"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="Rfs_id">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="Rfs_name" type="tns:Rfs_name"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="Rfs_name">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="Rfs" type="tns:Rfs"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Rfs">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="action">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="add"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="update"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="delete"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="status">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="new"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="inProgress"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="active"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="delete"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="characteristics" type="tns:Characteristic"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Does anyone know what is the problem?